# troubles with angular pagination as a different component

Tags: angular, pagination

i've created a pagination for my angular web app, and it worked just fine. but i duplicated the same code several times, each time for different page/component, and that's bad coding, so i created a new component for pagination.

then, instead of adding for every html file this chunk -

```
<pagination-template #p="paginationApi" [id]="config.id" (pageChange)="config.currentPage = $event">
  <div class="custom-pagination">
    <button class="previous" [class.disabled]="p.isFirstPage()"
    *ngIf="!p.isFirstPage()" (click)="previous()">previous</button>
    <div class="page-number" *ngFor="let page of p.pages" [class.current]="p.getCurrent() === page.value">
      <button class="not-current-page" (click)="onPageChange(page.value)" 
      *ngIf="p.getCurrent() !== page.value">{{ page.label }}</button> 
      <button class="current-page" *ngIf="p.getCurrent() === page.value">{{ page.label }}</button>            
    </div>
    <button class="next" [class.disabled]="p.isLastPage()" *ngIf="!p.isLastPage()" 
    (click)="next()">next</button>
  </div>
</pagination-template>
```

i simply wrote
`<app-pagination></app-pagination>`, but it didn't work.

the buttons are visible, but they don't change the pages, they just take me to the top of the current page.

here's the .ts file:

```
export class PaginationComponent implements OnInit {

  things: Thing[];
  searchInput = '';
  p: number = 1;
  config = {id: 'custom', maxSize: 3, itemsPerPage: 4, currentPage: 1};

  constructor(private router: Router, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe((data: { things: Thing[] }) => {
      this.things = data.things.slice().reverse();
    });
  }

  onPageChange(event) {
    this.config.currentPage = event;
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }

  previous() {
    this.config.currentPage--;
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }

  next() {
    this.config.currentPage++;
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }
}
```

thank :)))

Comment: You pagination component does not take config object as Input. Is it in purpose ? To me it looks like you update a config object which only lives within your pagination component, and it might be the problem

Comment: oh it might be that! new to angular and communication between components :) thanks!

Comment: it did, thanks! i just needed to learn a bit about input/output and eventemitters, but now it works :)))